# javascript / es6 - how to get index of first object value whos array length is greater than 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object which is full of arrays:

`const errors = { name: [], date: ['invalid format'], ... }`

I want to find the index (or object key, if I can't get an index) of the first value in the errors object where the array length is greater than one. So in the example above, the `date` array is the first array in the object that has a length, so I would just return, ideally, `1`, or `date` if necessary.

Anybody know the most concise / fastest way to do this in javascript / es6?

Comment: What do you mean by the index of an object property?

Comment: Objects are not ordered, so there is no "first" one and no "index" of the key. There's only the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()` on `Object.keys()` and it will return first result that matches condition or undefined.

```js
const errors = { name: [], date: ['invalid format']}
var result = Object.keys(errors).find(e => errors[e].length);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why not `.findIndex()` as OP wants the index preferably?

Comment: @yuriy636 Because an object does not have a guaranteed order of properties.

Comment: Are you sure that it will return first array object ?

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript objects have no inherent order to their properties**, so if an index is truly salient you probably want to use an array instead.

At that point it's just something like `errors.findIndex(e => e.length > 1)`, adjusted as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `for ..in` to loop through the object and  `Object.prototype.toString` to check if the value is an array.

Also to find the index you may need to use Object.keys which will create an array of keys from the object. Js Object does not have `index`

```js
const errors = {
  name: [],
  test: 1,
  date: ['invalid format'],
  test2: 2
}
for (var keys in errors) {
  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(errors[keys]) === '[object Array]' && errors[keys].length > 0) {
    console.log(errors[keys])
}
}
```

Comment: @str any specific reason to not use `Object.prototype.toString`?

Comment: @brk It's ugly, slow, long, hard to remember and can be spoofed in ES6.